# Spring Security session domain

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

My friend and I are making a Java spring boot application for University practice. Its front is on Firebase, and the API is on Heroku

The problem is the following, I configured Spring Security as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**", "/bid/getBids", "/bid/{id}", "/purchase/create",
                    "/purchase/{id}", "/purchase/question/{questionId}/answer").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/registration/**", "/registration").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);
}
```

While I'm testing the API on Heroku via swagger/postman, everything works fine, including role restrictions.

But when it tries to set up authorization via the /login path, it redirects to the swagger-ui page, because that's how I set it up. I rewrote the redirect to its main page on Firebase, but the session doesn't work that way, apparently because cookies are saved to the address of my application on Heroku.

Please tell me how I can configure Spring Security so that its site saves user sessions during authorization, and the site works normally with my API?

I use a translator for some phrases, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your frontend and backend applications are served on different domains and HTTP cookie information is stored for only the specific domain. So I think you can easily serve your static page (or single page application resources) by putting under src/resources/static of your spring boot application. By doing this you can also restrict your front-end application and allow for only authorized users. If you want to serve the front-end application on firebase and backend on Heroku you should forward it to the upstream host by configuring rewrite rules in the firebase.json file (https://firebase.google.cn/docs/hosting/full-config?authuser=0#rewrites).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The first option is not suitable for us, because it is a requirement to deploy to different hosting sites.